# How to repeatedly prompt for user input until it meets some criteria?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am creating a collector in discord.js version 13.6.0. At this point, my code is working fine, as far as what I want to have. What I don't know is how to query the user and get this information from them to tag roles. This is difficult for me because if I just add another variable and a condition to check if it's a role, it just kind of makes everything work twice and suddenly the collector stops. I would like everything to work in sequence and not stop when there is an error just to have the collector repeat so many times until someone gives a good value.

```js
const collector = await mainMessage.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter: filter, max: 2, time: 900000 });

collector.on("collect", (message) => {
    const priceItem = message.content;
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(priceItem))) return message.channel.send(`To nie liczba`);

    collector.stop();

    mainMessage.edit({
        content: `Nazwa: ${itemName}\nPieniadze: ${priceItem}.`,
    });
});

collector.on("end", () => {
    return message.channel.send(`123 123`);
});
```

Comment: Could you expand on what you are trying to accomplish here (e.g. "tag roles"), are you trying to make some sort of a shop?

Comment: @iris87 I'm trying to set up store for the economy. I would like the next collected message from the user to be any tagged role. If he writes anything else then the code will repeat until he does.

Comment: Your question seems to be an expansion on this one [1] 

Instead of a single criterion, now there's a continuous chain of potentially arbitrary validated input that form a sort of workflow. If you take this answer's [2] approach of isolating the collection into a recursive function, you can just repeat that pattern for each workflow step

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74753486/how-to-repeatedly-prompt-for-user-input-until-it-meets-some-criteria
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/74765792/1732820